# MDS and BIPLATFORM repositories are not found while installing through RCU

Tags: oracle11g, obiee, rcu

I am aiming to install OBIEE 11g.

1) I installed Oracle DB 11
2) Installed Oracle SQL Developer
3) Tested the connectivity and it worked
4) I have SYS, SYSDBA users running well with all the privileges
5) I downloaded RCU from Oracle for Windows 64 bit. I am running Windows 8.
6) While installing the RCU, I couldn't find the repositories MDS and BIPLATFORM. The only schemas I see are as shown in the picture.I have the sysdba privileges and I tested a test connection as SYS/SYSDBA through SQL developer successfully. [image]

Comment: I guess, you have not downloaded the correct RCU version. Maybe you've downloaded the BI Apps RCU.

Comment: OMG. You are rite. I downloaded Apps RCU.. Oracle Business Intelligence Applications RCU (11.1.1.7.1).... Thank You mate.Let me pull the rite one. I am sure that should solve my problem. Many Thanks.